# Get ContentDocument Id and ContentVersion Id of an attachment

Tags: apex, soql, attachment

I have to retrieve all the attachments of a custom object (of all records) and list them out with thumbnail and preview option.

For the preview option, I need the ContentDocument id and for the thumbnail, I need ContentVesrsion Id.

I need Record Id, Record Title, Attachment Id, ContentDocument Id, ContentVersion Id in the rows of the list.

I tried

```
select Id, Title__c, 
(SELECT Id, Name FROM Attachments)
from My_Object__c
```

But how can I get the ContentDocument Id and ContentVersion Id using the query? I am not sure how to proceed. Can I try something like this

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
(SELECT ContentDocumentId, 
(SELECT Id FROM ContentVersion WHERE isLatest=true) 
FROM ContentDocumentLink) 
FROM sample__c
```

I know the above query is wrong and I don't see how to use the ContentDocumentId in the where condition of ContentVersion query. I am confused. Please help. I have to fix the SOQL ASAP

Comment: are your Attachments being saved as Files in your org (that is, ContentVersions)?  You can't nest subqueries more than 1 deep in SOQL.  Basically, `select id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId IN (some list of obj Ids)` gets you all ContentDocuments and the latest version Id

Comment: Yes. Those are saved as files. I have already attained my goal with another approach. :)

Comment: @AeJey You should add your answer here, so it can help others as well :)